# Searching more than one position in a Multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was wondering how I could widen my search within a multi-dimensional array (2D) to more than just one position at a time.  Specifically I am trying to look in coords (X,Y) but also above, below, and to the sides of the original position.

ex) I am looking for an integer value of "0". If I search in any given row or column of the 2D array I need to also be searching in the surrounding positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for-loop to search for the surroundings in a 2D array:

```
for(int x=(x1-1); x<=(x1+1); x++) //Check on all 8 directions
    for(int y=(y1-1); y<=(y1+1); y++)
        if(x!=-1 && y!=-1 && x!=height && y!=width) //Check to ensure you are within bounds
            //do whatever..
            //e.g: if(array[x][y] == 0); count++;
```

`x1` and `y1` is the coordinate of the center of your surrounding.

In the if-statement, you can add more checks such as checking the coordinates `x!=x1 && y!= y1`

You may be tempted to use a long series of 8 if-else statements to check all directions, but that is not necessary (and prone to mistakes).